# initialization for array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, array-push

I want to dynamically create arrays of arrays and I have no clue how to initialize my arrays...

Here is the code:

```
$resT= array();
$resR= array();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
   if ($obj == NULL) continue;
   $c="XX";
   if (test1)         $c=$obj['GC'];
   array_push($resT[$c],$obj['AT']);
   array_push($resR[$c],$obj['AR']);
}
```

I got this: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array

Thanks,

Amir.

Comment: You should use other variable names: `$resT`, `$resR`, `$obj` and so on are not very useful names. A variable name should always speak for itself.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$resT= array();
$resR= array();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
   if ($obj == NULL) continue;
   $c="XX";
   if (test1)         $c=$obj['GC'];
    if(!isset($resT[$c]))
      $resT[$c] = array();
    if(!isset($resR[$c]))
      $resR[$c] = array();
   array_push($resT[$c],$obj['AT']);
   array_push($resR[$c],$obj['AR']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked... I am newbie... I didn't know about isset() function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use array_push.

You can use the shorthand notation of

```
$resT= array();
$resR= array();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
   if ($obj == NULL) continue;
   $c="XX";
   if (test1)         $c=$obj['GC'];
   $resT[$c] = array();
   $resT[$c][] = $obj['AT'];
   $resR[$c] = array();
   $resR[$c][] = $obj['AR'];
}
```

Comment: You re-create `$resT[$c]` (`$resR[$c]` respectively) in every iteration. This means every `$resT[$c]` contains only the last element for every value of `$c`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish but this should resolve your PHP notice at least:

```
$resT= array();
$resR= array();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
   if ($obj == NULL) continue;
   $c="XX";
   if (test1)         $c=$obj['GC'];

   if(!is_array($resT[$c])){
      $resT[$c] = array();
   }

   if(!is_array($resR[$c])){
      $resR[$c] = array();
   }

   array_push($resT[$c],$obj['AT']);
   array_push($resR[$c],$obj['AR']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resT= array();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
  if (!is_null($obj)) {
    $c = $test1 ? $obj['GC'] : "XX";
    if (!array_key_exists($c, $resT)) $resT[$c] = array();
    $resT[$c][] = $obj['AT'];
  }
}
$resR = $resT;
```